# How can I plot graph for students' attendance from csv files using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My CSV file:

```
NAME,1,2,3,4,5
Marcelo,A,A,A,A,A
Benzema,A,A,A,A,A
Navas,A,A,A,A,A
CR,A,A,A,A,A
Varane,P,P,P,A,P
Carvajal,A,A,A,A,A
Modric,A,A,A,A,A
Kroos,A,A,A,A,A
Ramos,A,A,A,A,A
```

A = Absent, P = Present

I would like to generate a bar chart using pandas that can show percentage of the students' attendance based on the Present and Absence value.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('attendance.csv')
    
ax = df.plot(x="NAME", y="1", kind="bar")
df.plot(x="NAME", y="1", kind="bar", ax=ax, color="maroon")
```

I am using '1' in y-axis is to test either it can plot the graph based on the Column '1' given.

However the error says:
`TypeError: no numeric data to plot`

The issue is because the value String is passed, right? So, how can I read string values and plot them.

Answer (score 0):

You should aggregate the data in pandas first. An easy way as you have binary values (A/P) is to check equality to P, then get the [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) per row/column depending on the desired output.

For a percentage per student you can use:

```
ax = df.set_index('NAME').eq('P').mean(axis=1).mul(100).plot.bar()
ax.set_ylim(0, 105)
```

Or for percentage per day:

```
ax = df.set_index('NAME').eq('P').mean(axis=0).mul(100).plot.bar()
ax.set_ylim(0, 105)
```

Output per student:

[image]

Output per day:

[image]

##### plotting all categories

```
(df.melt('NAME', var_name='day', value_name='status')
   .value_counts(subset=['NAME', 'status']).unstack()
   .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Or:

```
s = df.set_index('NAME').stack().droplevel(-1).rename('status')

pd.crosstab(s.index, s).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Great! but the graph shows only for particular value like this one 'P'. How can I combine both value in one graph?

Comment: See update for an arbitrary number of categories